# Why are the first 4-6 characters from ssh-keygen (RSA) the same everytime?

Tags: keys, ssh

New to StackExchange, so please bear with the newbie.

At my current job we are often creating many ssh keys with ssh-keygen (RSA). One thing I have noticed is that the first few characters (say the first 5 or so) of the private key are consistently the same. These are all created on the same computer. Is this to be expected? I am just curious why this would be the case.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5944/why-do-all-ssh-rsa-keys-begin-with-aaaab3nzac1yc?rq=1

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer, I am looking at the private, not public, keys. Is there a similar concept with private ssh keys?

Comment: Edit your question to make it clear you are talking about private keys. I think that it is something similar, though.

Comment: And please include an example private key in string format (hexadecimals if binary). List the program + version you used to create the key pair & stored the private key for.